# Creating new Associative collection and adding new items in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

Here's my sample code.

```
$users = 3 users //suppose

$leaders = new Collection();

foreach($users as $user)
{
    $name = $user->name;
    $username = $user->username;
    $leaders->put('name', $name);
    $leaders->put('username', $username);
}
dd($leaders);
```

This gives me the result for only one user (The 3rd user)

```
Collection {#274 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "name" => "user3"
    "username" => "username3"
  ]
}
```

Because `put()` is replacing the values with the same keys.

I tried with this too:

```
$leaders->push($name);
$leaders->push($username);
```

But I am getting:

```
Collection {#274 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => "user1"
    1 => "username1"
    2 => "user2"
    3 => "username2"
    4 => "user3"
    5 => "username3"
  ]
}
```

**How to create different item arrays for different users?**

**Update #1**: Got the answer.
Now trying to display the values on the view like this:

```
@foreach($leaders as $leader)
    {{ $leader->username }}
@endforeach
```

**Error**: Trying to get property of non-object.

Is this not supposed to work this way for custom collections?

**Update #2:** Nevermind. Found it.

It is supposed to work this way: `{{ $leader['username'] }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try push method

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $leaders->push([
        'name' => $user->name,
        'username' => $user->username,
    ])
}
```

Comment: Damn this was so simple. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell me how will I be able to display it on the view? I have updated my question. Please check.